# Apple Shortcut HTTPs not working on Apple Watch

Tags: https, apple-watch, lets-encrypt, sirishortcuts

I use the cool feature in Apple Shortcut to request some HTTP REST commands of my Smarthome via my Webserver. I use an apache2 with Lets Encrypt certificates.

This is working fine on my iPad and on my iPhone but unfortunately not on my Apple Watch. I get always: `The certificate for this server is invalid. You might connecting to a server that is pretending to be "my.domain.com" which could put your confidential information at risk`.

I use the "URL" command in Apple shortcuts with "Network".

I am not sure how to handle this. On all my Apple devices the short cuts are working but not on the Apple Watch. I restarted the watch already.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on myself.

First I tested the certificate with https://ssllabs.com from Qualys. This site tests the certificate. The result showed that the chainfile will not be downloaded from the apache2. The mistake was that I forgot to add the "SSLCertificateChainFile" to the configuration.

Now my apache2 SSL configuration is rate A+ and the shortcuts are working again with the Apple Watch.

Why the error only occured on the apple watch and not on the other apple devices too I don't know.

Thanks